# onclick show/hide push content down

Tags: jquery, css, hide, show

I am creating a small mobile prototype. I can get my content to push down on show/hide. Here is my code please help! I am not sure where the problem lies. I think its around maybe putting in a position: relative or another attribute. I am looking to get this fixed as soon as possible. If you could point me in the right direction of how I could get this fixed it would be very appreciated. I think my divs are stacked correctly but I am not sure. It has been awhile since I have coded and I am a little rusty.

```
    <body>
    <div id="header">
        <a href="#" onclick="overlayvis(showhideme)"><img src="images/header.gif"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="nav" id="showhideme" style="visibility: hidden; display: block; position relative;">
        <div id="content">
               <p><img src="images/nav.png"></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrap">
        <div id="content">
            <p>
                <img src="images/body.jpg" border="0" usemap="#Map">
                <map name="Map" id="Map">
                    <area shape="rect" coords="3,1727,638,1804" href="#top" alt="back to top" />
                    <area shape="rect" coords="31,1853,611,1940" href="tel:+18005555555" alt="tap to call" />               
                </map>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <a href="#content"><img src="images/footer.png"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: do you have a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the inline styles and add `class="somebutton"` to your link. Then use the following jQuery.

```
$('a.somebutton').on('click', function(){
    $('#showhideme').animate({height:'toggle'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope, you are looking JQuery Mobile accordions, please look the link, it may help you,

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/accordions/